Wireguard on mikrotik - no internet connection
I have mirotik with Wireguard on AWS EC2, but I have problem with internet connection after connect to WG. My config which I get from mikrotik
[Interface]
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = [private_key]
Address = 10.0.101.2
DNS = 8.8.8.8,1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = [public_key]
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = endpoint_IP:45771

My router config

IPAddresses

My Firewall Rules

NAT

IP Routes

The problem is that when I connect to wireguard, I can access resources that are behind VPN, for example, but I can't open Google, for example. I tried to add subnets from VPC to AllowedIPs, but it didn't help, I still have the same problem that after connecting to VPN, my internet doesn't work.
On AWS I have one VPC with 6 subnets
10.0.203.0/24
10.0.202.0/24
10.0.201.0/24
10.0.102.0/24
10.0.101.0/24
10.0.103.0/24

I have no idea where I went wrong that my internet doesn't work. I wanted to make it so that the VPN is only used when I ask for resources on its end, and not have it route all my traffic through it.
Any idea what I did wrong?

I don't what exactly would happen when the "server" is a router, but at least you can try changing "Allowed Address" from 0.0.0.0/0 to 10.0.101.0/24.

@TomYan When I change from 0.0.0.0/0 to 10.0.101.0/24 then my internet is very slow 1Mb/s. Of course I have access to resource for VPN, but internet works very slow.

@TomYan I know here is the problem, problem was license, because I have "Free" which is limited to 1Mbit
